# Solarized color scheme doesn't work Mac Terminal.app

Tags: vimrc, terminal, colorscheme, macos

I want to use the Solarized Light theme in both my Terminal and VIM.

I seem to have got it working in Terminal, I downloaded the entire package from their website, `tree` output, and then in my terminal preferences I imported the `Solarized Light xterm-256color` profile from the download.

[image]

And I set this as my default profile and it seems to look ok:

[image]

Then, I proceeded to try to set VIM's color scheme to Solarized Light as well, so I git-cloned git://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized.git into my `~/.vim/bundle` (I use Pathogen).

See a paste bin of some `ls` and `tree` outputs in my `~/.vim/bundle` [here](http://pastebin.com/5uQW7RwD)

But even after adding the correct information to [my vimrc](http://pastebin.com/NcXHJAKu) it looks really ugly:

[image]

Why does it not seem to work? You can see around the edges of the terminal the colors it should be, why is the text so unreadable and the background color so ugly?

Comment: try `:set colorscheme` and tab to see if solarized option  is there.

Comment: What's the value of `t_Co` and what's in $TERM? Have you tried setting `g:solarized_termcolors` to 256 (before calling `colorscheme solarized`)?

Comment: @Ashok `set colorscheme` tells me: `E518: Unknown option: colorscheme`, however `colorscheme ^D` tells me that solarized is an option.

Comment: @grodzik `t_Co` is 256, `$TERM` is `xterm-256color`, and I have not tried setting `g:solarized_termcolors` _before_ setting `colorscheme`, however setting it afterwards seems to change nothing.

Comment: @theonlygusti sorry its :colorscheme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by setting `g:solarized_termcolors` to `16` instead of `256`.

```
let g:solarized_termcolors=16
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users), you should set `g:solarized_termcolors` to `256`, but you need to do that before calling `colorscheme solarized`

```
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
colorscheme solarized
```

Comment: This uses colors different to the one in the screenshots on the main site.

Comment: See [here](http://i.cubeupload.com/zz8VNv.png) - on the right is my terminal

Comment: So I can't help much more here then, I'm not a Mac user. One only thing that I could suggest is to check `g:solarized_termtrans`. On solarized page in `Option details` section there is a note about Mac Terminal.app, maybe that will help you. That one eventually needs to be set before calling `colorscheme solarized` as well.